# Can I hang a hammock from a anchor in mortar?

Tags: brick, hanging, mortar

Can I hang a hammock from mortar?

I have a hammock that I’m wanting to put up in my back yard. The only way I can achieve this is by using the brick wall and my wooden fence post. The anchor point I got for the brick is a 4 3/8 inch steel lap screw with a hook. The screw is ab 5/16” thick. I just wanna make sure it can hold at least 200 pounds but it would be nice if it could hold ~300 pounds. I have no idea about this stuff so if anyone has any other ideas or thoughts please share. Thanks!

Comment: the wooden fence might not like that

Comment: I think between the chance of destroying my fence or my wall or dropping a person out of a hammock, I'd opt for a steel hammock stand.  They are not expensive.  There are too many unknowns in your plan, too many things that were built without your hammock in mind.

Comment: "The brick wall"? Is this a free standing structure? A load bearing brick wall from your house? A veneer brick wall attached to your house? Assuming that the hammock rope hangs at 15°, the half of 200 pounds going to each end gets converted into a tension force of (100 pounds)/(sin 15°) = 390 pounds. And there's a dynamic load when you climb onto it, so I would design each connection for 600 pounds.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just guessing and using screws that won't pivot with the motion of the hammock, GOOGLE hammock brackets and get something that's designed for a hammock like the one shown below from Amazon. Each hook will hold 850 pounds for a total of 1700 pounds.

[image]

Comment: This is good advice, but I believe OP's main question is whether a 5/16" screw can be mounted to a brick wall in a way that will do this job.  By following this answer, that question just changes to 4 #10 screws (or whatever fits in these brackets).  And while those carabiners are probably fine, I'd use quick links for this job.

Answer (score 1):

The 5/16" screw hook will be inadequate. See [this analogous eyebolt](https://www.boltdepot.com/Product-Details.aspx?product=12282) with a working load limit of 100 pounds, where the safety factor of 4 implies a 400 pound ultimate strength.

Assuming that your ropes leave their supports at a 15° down angle, your fence and brick wall need to restrain about 600 pounds of horizontal force each, where there's a 1.5 safety factor on top of your 200 pounds weight to account for dynamic loads. I'm uncomfortable with such a small safety factor. I would want to design the anchorage at your walls for one 200 pound person getting pounced on by another 200 pound person (I don't trust brick veneer to stand up to the stresses unless you get lucky about placing the anchorage close to a wall tie).

*That 600 pounds comes from 1.5(1/2)(200#)/(tan 15°) = 560#.*